# Nginx -- Wordpress multisite with root folder in own directory

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, nginx

I have my Wordpress files in a directory called wed. I also have the following rewrite rules in my Nginx config:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ last;
      rewrite ^/(wp-.*.php)$ /web/$1 last;
      rewrite ^/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /web/$1 last;
}
```

So I can have the site on / but all files in /web. It woks but I cant view my other sites on my network. If I access one of the sites I only get an white-screen and if I try to access the wp-admin on a multisite site I get a redirect loop.
I tries to enable debug, error files are also blank.

How should I configure my Nginx?

```
Wordpress files: /web
main site: /
```

---

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'virre.cf');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```